# 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; - shows in my website

Tags: mysql, sql

I was working on my new joomla website changed some appearing sittings then the syntax error came out in the main page and changed all the website design I tried to undo all the changes I made and the error still there 
the message I got

> 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near ') AND c.access_view IN (0,1,1,5) AND c.restriction_18=0 ORDER BY
>   i.date_start D' at line 2

```
SELECT i.*,c.id as c_id, c.name as c_name,c.alias as c_alias,c.icon_url as c_icon_url,
r.name as r_name, img.path as img_path, img.name as img_name, img.ext as img_ext,
img.caption as img_caption
FROM l0ucm_djcf_categories c, l0ucm_djcf_items i
LEFT JOIN l0ucm_djcf_regions r ON r.id=i.region_id
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT img.id, img.item_id, img.name, img.path, img.ext, img.ordering, img.caption
     FROM (SELECT * FROM l0ucm_djcf_images WHERE type='item' ORDER BY ordering) img GROUP BY img.item_id ) AS img

ON img.item_id=i.id 
WHERE i.date_exp > '2015-07-25 16:44:45' AND i.published = 1 AND c.published = 1 
AND i.cat_id=c.id AND i.cat_id IN (9,10,11,12,13,15) 
AND i.type_id IN () AND c.access_view IN (0,1,1,5) AND c.restriction_18=0

ORDER BY i.date_start DESC limit 9
```

anyone can help me to find out from where I can solve this problem?

thank you all,

Comment: also look for the fusing of old style joins in line 4 (from c,l) with explicit joins. In addition keep an eye out for img alias twice about a few keystrokes away from each other

Comment: An `IN ()` expression cannot be empty. If you have a variable populating that `()` grouping, you must verify that it has a non-empty value before passing it to the SQL. We cannot assist in debugging it further without the code that generated that SQL.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the statement `AND i.type_id IN ()`.

`IN()` function cannot get an empty value. You should check the php code that creates the query and add a validation to the variable to add the statement only if it not empty.

Comment: Thank you guys but still the problem not solved ! you find the coz of the error which is IN() function shouldn't get an empty value , where I have to go to which file to solve this issue ?? or what sitting in end-back I have to change that IN() function not return empty value ?

Comment: You have to provide the php code that creates the query.